# Cannnot get ng2-charts to work. [ng2-charts (Not Found) zone.js]

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I have followed everything from the website : http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/

1. npm install ng2-charts --save
2. npm install chart.js --save

Then I added this script link in my HTML  :

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```

Next I added my import statements :

[image]

Because of the import statement I now get an error thrown in the zone.js code.

> GET http://localhost:3000/ng2-charts 404 (Not Found) zone.js:2019

Is this the correct way to import ng2-charts? Or am I missing something. I am fairly new to angular2.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/321

Comment: so i should add "ng2-charts": "node_modules/ng2-charts", to my map in the systemjs.config.js file?

Comment: yeah, this issue actually describes it better - https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/324

Comment: thanks, a bit messy, but it works now